# PHP MYSQL returning string field as numeric

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL database that has a table with a column (`field1`) of type `TINYTEXT`. The column contains values such as `010101` and `01010`" etc… which are actually filenames.

When I query this table using PHP it seems to be deciding that this field is numeric and it thus strips off the leading zero.  When I try to use this value as a filename of course it doesn't work.

I am extracting the data like this:

```
$sSQL      = "SELECT * FROM images;";
$rsImageList = RunQuery($sSQL);
$iLoop = 0;
while (($iLoop <= 80) && ($aRow = mysql_fetch_array($rsImageList))) {
  extract($aRow);
  echo $field1;
  $iLoop++;
}
```

How can I typecast the variable as a string type?

---

Mea culpa!  I had managed to get duplicate data in my table, some entries with the leading zero missing already (thanks to Excel which I used to import the data) and some without. I was looking at the correct data but extracting the incorrect data. Moral of the story - test with only a couple of lines of data not 60!

Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: What if you use `var_dump` instead? What if you modify your code so that it could be obvious that it's php that converts it (at this moment it's not obvious at all - what if your original data is already broken?)?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($aRow['field1']);` inside your while loop?

Comment: I just tested `extract()` with `$a=array('Test1'=>'010101','Test2'=>'000101453401'); extract($a); echo 'Test1 is:'.$Test1;` and got `Test1 is: 010101`. It seems if you put a string in, you get a string out, so your problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks all. I am using the extract because there are four or five fields I want (not shown for brevity). Doing var_dump on $aRow shows the leading zero missing. As I mentioned below, the data is correct in the database (viewed with HeidiSQL) so the problem would seem to be where the data is being read from MYSQL by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

you can force by casting it to a string:

```
$var = "" . $aRow["column"];
```

Comment: That's true, but I don't think its his problem. He's using extract for one, and we don't know for certain if it's being altered on the insert, by MySQL, or by the extract function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAST()` function to change it into string

```
$sSQL = "SELECT CAST(field1 AS CHAR) FROM images;";
```

Give it a try, I dont think its MySQL fault as you have defined it as `TINYTEXT` maybe its because `extract()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys.  Neither of them worked :-(. The data is correct in the MQYSQL database (viewed using HeidiSQL). When I exam $aRow in my debugger before the extract it is already missing the leading zero.

Comment: would you show us the `RunQuery()` function, and also check data in phpMyAdmin, make sure it okey there